# como uso push dentro de un forEach con express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ejs

Necesito que `ar = []` obtenga los objetos que proporciona el ciclo

```
if (user.rol == 'estudiante') {
  let ar = []
  const consulta = await Relacion.find({ idUser: user.id });
  
  consulta.forEach(async element => {
    const objeto = await Materia.findById(element.idMateria);
    ar.push(objeto)
  });
  console.log(ar);
  
  res.render('estudiantes/materias', { username: user.nombre, mat: ar });
}
```

Comment: Por que no utilizas una función que cree un nuevo vector ya que por cada elemento del vector haces una búsqueda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes una función asíncrona y `forEach` no espera a que dichas funciones se terminen antes de continuar con la ejecución. Puedes reemplazarlo por `map` y `Promise.all`, el código quedaría así:

```
if (user.rol == 'estudiante') {
  const consulta = await Relacion.find({ idUser: user.id });
  
  const ar = await Promise.all(consulta.map(async element => {
    return Materia.findById(element.idMateria);
  }));

  console.log(ar);
  
  res.render('estudiantes/materias', { username: user.nombre, mat: ar });
}
```

[Array.prototype.map() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Promise.all() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: vale eso funciona, muchísimas gracias